# Responsive styles with flex box while using min max property

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox, responsive-design

I am trying to make a responsive design with CSS flexbox. Here is the details that I am trying to achieve.

1. Display items with max-width:300px in flex-direction row.
2. When we shrink the browser window the items from one row will stay in same line until the individual item width becomes 200px, min-width:200px. When the width reaches to min-width:200px the items from the right side will move to the next line.

I am not able to accomplish this task with flex box. Is there anybody can help me with this. It will be highly appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Here is the code, I have tried so far:

```
 .wrapper{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  }
  .content{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    width:95%;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .header{
      display:flex;
      justify-content:space-between;
      margin-top:16px;
      padding-left:20px;
      background: #E0E3E7;
      border-radius: 4px;
      min-height: 56px;
  }
  .box{
      background: #F0F2F3;
      border-radius: 4px;
      display:flex;
      flex-direction:row;
      flex-wrap:wrap;
      min-height:119px;
  }
  .box-item{
      background: #FFFFFF;
      border-radius: 4px;
      border: 1px solid #C2C7CF;
      max-width:300px;
      min-width:200px;
      width:100%;
      height:56px;
      margin-left:32px;
      margin-right:32px;
      margin-top:10px;
      margin-bottom:10px;
  }
```

And, here is fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/961ruj3q/32/

Answer (score 0):

I would add for example a min-width: 264px to the  so that the input does not come out of the container. And for the other problem, as the max-width is 100%, the input will always take the maximum size, which is 300px, so you can't make it 200px until the container is smaller.

you could use media query to set a smaller input size when the screen is too.

PS: I'm also new to using Flexbox and that's the solution I can think of. Greetings and I hope I have helped you